# PHP comparing dateTime not working

Tags: php, datetime

Hi I have my query where when the current time is greater than the time in my db that has the data type of `DateTime` some fields will be updated but its not working can you check my code for my mistakes. Thanks here is my code.

```
<?php
include_once("connection.php");

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
$timeNow = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

echo $timeNow;

$void1 = 'void';

$sql = " UPDATE tbl_accepted SET downPaymentValidity = '$void1' WHERE downPaymentTime < '$timenow'";


$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if($result > 0){
echo "success";
exit();
}else{
echo "failed with error - " . mysqli_error($conn);
exit();
}
?>
```

here is the format inside the `downPaymentTime` variable `2017-01-24 16:22:23`

Comment: In your PHP, you're getting the date as per `Asia/Manila` timezone. I suppose your database has date in UTC timezone. That's possibly why it's not working as expected.

Comment: @ObjectManipulator - but when I echo the `$timenow` the real time here in ph working fine. Will the UTC timezone will still be the one to be compared with the `downPaymentTime` ?

Comment: any how current time will be greater than old time which is stored in db rt?

Comment: @AmruthLS - again sir? I'm sorry can't quite understand. But im comparing the time now with the time inside my db.

Comment: @BatzbatzFuentes i mean current time will be always greater than old time which is stored in db. that condition no need i think ... and its typo error check spelling of $timeNow

Comment: @AmruthLS - ohhhh, so how can the time in db be less than the time I'm comparing it with.

Comment: @BatzbatzFuentes oh ok ok sry

Answer (score 0):

In this line `'$void1' WHERE downPaymentTime < '$timenow'";` the variable `$timenow` should be `$timeNow`

Answer (score 0):

Update your query to NOW() instead of php time.

> $sql = " UPDATE tbl_accepted SET downPaymentValidity = '$void1' WHERE downPaymentTime < NOW()";

Comment: are you sure connecting to db?